# Distorted App screen - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

Our app looks like this on Huawei 8510, and android version is 2.3.5.
This screenshot came from our customer. We disabled screenshot on app, so our customer used another phone to take screenshot.

How is it possible?

[image]

this is layout code that i think there is no problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<com.asdasd.asdasd.controls.CMScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scvAgreement"
    style="@style/pm_ContentStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAgreement"
        style="@style/pm_TextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pm_content_padding_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/pm_content_padding_right"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:typeface="monospace" />
</com.asdasd.asdasd.controls.CMScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        style="@style/pm_ButtonStyle_Standart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onBtnNegativeClicked"
        android:text="@string/pgPrivacy_btnNotAccept"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pm_middle_text_size"
        android:singleLine="false"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendAgreement"
        style="@style/pm_ButtonStyle_Standart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pm_button_margin_left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_black"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onBtnSendAgreement"
        android:text="@string/pgPrivacy_btnSendAgreement"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pm_middle_text_size"
        android:singleLine="false"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPositive"
        style="@style/pm_ButtonStyle_Standart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pm_button_margin_left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_orange"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onBtnPositiveClicked"
        android:text="@string/pgPrivacy_btnAccept"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pm_middle_text_size"
        android:singleLine="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And also, our custom listView

```
public class CMScrollView extends ScrollView {
public static final String LOG_TAG = "com.asdasd.asdasd.controls.CMScrollView";
private OnScrollViewReachedToEnd onScrollViewReachedToEnd;

public CMScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet st) {
    super(context, st);
}

public OnScrollViewReachedToEnd getOnScrollViewReachedToEnd() {
    return onScrollViewReachedToEnd;
}

public void setOnScrollViewReachedToEnd(OnScrollViewReachedToEnd onScrollViewReachedToEnd) {
    this.onScrollViewReachedToEnd = onScrollViewReachedToEnd;
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY() + view.getTop()));// Calculate the scrolldiff
    if (diff == 0) {  // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
        if (ApplicationController.DEBUGMODE)
            Log.d(CMScrollView.LOG_TAG, "MyScrollView: Bottom has been reached");
        if (onScrollViewReachedToEnd != null) {
            onScrollViewReachedToEnd.onReachedToEnd(this);
        }
    }
    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}

public interface OnScrollViewReachedToEnd {
    void onReachedToEnd(IngScrollView scrollView);
}}
```

on AndroidManifest GL Version:

```
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Much more information is needed for anyone to try and help you. An Android version would help to start.

Comment: And Also, I have no idea which information should I give you about. I have any idea, @Peter.

Comment: We are at least going to need to see the source to be able to say anything about this at all. Are you creating your GUI using standard views or are you using RenderScript or some kind of OpenGL library?

Comment: Yes, we are using standard controls, @SubliemeSiem

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem, not a software problem. If this is only detected by one user, be patient and wait if there more than this one.

Answer (score 1):

One of my friend found a promising Answer after a lot of time & search.

The same kind of issue (Flickering in GUI) is solved by simply **Turn OFF the Developer Options**

[image]

Because if you enable hardware overlay , **GPU** will be takes care of UI & sometimes there will be some  conflict in **GUI rendering**.